# I2S voltage shifters needed?

Tags: audio, level-shifting, esp32, i2s

I am designing the schematics for my new PCB and I need to output some audio signals (totally new to this).

I am using an ESP32-SOLO-1 as MCU and the TFA9879HN as audio driver. The TFA9879HN is powered from 1.8 V, and the ESP-32 is powered from 3.3 V. I would like to know if it is necessary and possible to implement an I2C voltage level shifter with a MOSFET.

I have read that no pull-ups are needed, but the high frequencies concern me. SCK's frequency is 8..96 kHz and LRCK's frequency is 32~64 times SCK's frequency, so up to 6.144 MHz.

I think the MOSFET may not be fast enough. I am planning to use the Nexperia BSS138BKS from Nexperia and can simplify the BOM if I can use it for the multiple voltage shifts I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second page of datasheet says the digital inputs are 3.3V tolerant in the general features. Thus no I2S voltage shifting needed.

Comment: Many thanks fot the feedback, I think this is what I was looking for and did not see in the datasheet

Answer (score 0):

[Edited to address both I2C and I2S interfaces]

No need to level-shift the I2C bus (to the on-chip I2C controller), only need to make sure the pull-up resistors are tied to the 3.3V supply. Since the TFA9879HN chip is tolerant of 3.3V digital inputs, and because I2C is an open-collector interface, then the bus will operate at the 3.3V levels to match the ESP32-SOLO-1. See here from the datasheet:

[image]

Be careful about the value of the pull-up resistors though, too strong and the ESP32-SOLO-1 may not be able to meet the maximum ViL parameter (0.3*1.8V=0.54V) of the TFA9879HN, see here in the datasheet:

[image]

The I2S interface on the TFA9879HN is **INPUTS** only, and since all digital inputs are 3.3V tolerant, then no level-shift is required on this interface too. See here:

[image]

Comment: i2c is not the same thing as i2s...

Comment: @vicatcu - Very good point indeed. I assumed the OP was discussing I2C since that was mentioned in the question (as the I2C voltage level shifter) and the TFA9879HN is strictly I2C interface only.

Comment: i2c or i2s? ...

Comment: @icodeplenty It has I2C and I2S. I2S is an industry standard digital audio bus and as already commented, not like I2C.

Comment: Both vicatcu and TypeIA mentioned this, and yet my eyes only saw the I2C block in the block diagram. Point well taken now, thanks. So the question may be about both I2C and I2S interfaces or only one of them, but the OP needs to clarify this.

Comment: Since the I2S interface are inputs only, again no need to level shift because the TFA9879HN is 3.3V tolerant for all digital inputs.

Comment: Many thanks to everyone for the discussion and clarifications. The question was about I2S (somehow someone edited my question and I whink it is quite confuse now).
As pointed out, I think this should work nicely without level shifters, I will take care of the pull-up resistors and maybe use a 0603 instead of 0402 package in order to replace those I2C pull-up resistors easily (as I have read elsewhere, I2S does not need pull-up resistors, and being the TFA9879HN just listening and not controlling the I2S lines the voltage levels are OK)